# Terminology For Web Development and General Programming/Software?

Tags: terminology

EDIT: I should clarify. THe particular terms I listed below I fully understand. I also understand w3schools doesn't have the greatest information. These are just examples. I don't expect everybody to understand what an example is, but I hope the majority do.

Does anybody have any resources listing terms related to programming and web development, or care to pitch in?

Things like:

Runtime
Build time
Framework
Library
Normalize

I'm primarily a PHP developer so anything about that. I really am looking for general terms and specific terms related to web development, PHP, SQL, CSS, HTML.

Appreciate any input.

Couple I found:

http://www.w3schools.com/site/site_glossary.asp
http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/fundamentals/concepts.xml

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that you don't understand some of these listed concepts as a PHP developer, but nobody should have to explain to you what a Library or a Framework is.  If you can't even define a Library and you aren't a first year CS student then you have no business writing code.

Comment: Also, unless you are an absolute beginner, try to avoid W3Schools.  They routinely have bad and false information on their pages.

Comment: Google can give quick definitions. You search for the phrase "define: $someword" and Google will try to return any dictionary definitions it has.

Comment: Search the terms you're interested in, in Wikipedia. That should help with to get started.  Wikipedia is not the best resource for this, but it will get you moving in a direction.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I think you need to step back, take a deep breath and think about what you're saying. These are EXAMPLES. To take this opportunity to flame php developers is pathetic and immature. And you call yourself a higher-than-thou programmer? lol get over yourself

Comment: @user20385: Ah, so you are looking for a general-purpose glossary of terms (better than the W3Schools version)?

Comment: That is correct. As already said w3schools isn't great. I'm looking for a reliable source for definitions related to programming, php, html, css and sql.

Comment: @user20385, How was I flaming?  PHP is an interpreted language so I wouldn't begrudge someone with knowledge only in interpreted languages for not knowing what "Build time" is.  That is really all I meant.

Comment: Further, I apologize for assuming you were some punk kid who slept through school.  I didn't realize you were trying to build a legitimate list of definitions.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I respect somebody who apologizes for their wrongful assumptions. Let's just leave it at that. This is the trouble, there is a 'build time' when developing some web applications. But regardless, even general programming terms I'm interested in. I feel a huge list of resources would give me enough data to build my own personalized dictionary, a personal high level overview of everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Computing terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aComputing_terminology) from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) would be my suggestion for a resource though do keep in mind that some terms can be quite overloaded.

As an example of overload, consider the term library.  To some people it is a building with books in it while to others it is compiled machine code and the last L of a DLL.  Thus beware of the context of the term.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a browser with some smarts like Firefox or Chrome (not sure about IE as I only use that under duress ;).  Just highlight the phrases, right click and look them up.  Or just browse to Google (or your preferred search engine) and type them in.  For most of those terms, I think starting at Wikipedia would give you a good jumping off point too.

Comment: Hi, just edited to clarify. I don't need a lesson on particular terms. I want a huge list of resources covering all terms. I want a bucket of terminology, 1500 specialist words at least I should know.

Answer (score 1):

I write code and haven't had formal training in cs. My approach is pretty simple.

**It can be complex** 
 
The only sensible way to eat an elephant is, one small piece at a time. Accept the fact that you can't take it all in at once.

**Context** 
There is SO much to learn, that it doesn't make sense trying to learn everything at once. Try to understand in detail things around the immediate problem you are trying to solve. This will give you context, and that context will give you a deeper understanding of what the concept is rather than an intellectual exercise.

A JavaScript library sounds beautiful and makes so much sense when you understand what jQuery is and have used it.

Understanding the concept of framework is so much more easier to understand when you've worked on CodeIgniter hands on and made a simple project on it.

Something that's very general and basic is concept of OOP and how it works in the language you are working with.

Read relevant(to what you are working on) technical blogs/stackoverflow/books and slowly you'll start picking up on stuff here and there, this will build incrementally and probably in a years time, with lot of coding/reading/understanding behind you, you'll know better.

If you come across something new, open its wikipedia page, `define:`"the concept"   google what does "the concept" mean, open 5 tabs from the results and open youtube, search for "the concept tutorial" and you'll get to know what you are dealing with in no time.

If nothing works, search for, and then ask on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of humor (or code in a fashion similar to mine) the following terminology should be applied:

- [FUBAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR) (Alternatively [Foobar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar))
- [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIGO)

On a more serious note:

- [Ternary Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)
- [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)
- [Server-Side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_side) vs. [Client-Side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_side), likewise:
  [Server-Side Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_side_scripting) vs. [Client-Side Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)
- [Style sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_sheet_%28web_development%29)
- [Maintainability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability)
- [Code Refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

And the list goes on.